# Dynamically change UITableViewCell's accessory view image

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a CustomTableView Cell and it has an accessory view. How can I change the accessory view's image dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Use your custom button for accessoryview like..

// stick the pencil icon on the accessory view

```
UIButton* pencil = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[pencil setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-pencil.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
pencil.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15);
pencil.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[pencil addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapEditButton:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
cell.accessoryView = pencil;
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use accessoryView, just place another imageView and change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In the init method of the custom cell, you can do something like (assuming ARC btw):

```
UIImage *customBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom_btn"];
UIButton *customBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, customBtnImg.size.width, customBtnImg.size.height)];
customBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[customBtn setBackgroundImage:customBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.accessoryView = customBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

modifications to the cell except  textColor and detailTextColor of cell should be done in the `willDisplayCell:` method and not the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method ,
the solution for your question is as follows --

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cellforIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageName:@"image.png" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,28,28) ;

    cell.accessoryView = btn ;

}
```

this code will definitely work !!

Comment: Can I ask why modifications should be done in willDisplayCell rather than cellForRowAtIndexPath ?